# How to use markdown syntax to write math in Hugo?

Tags: markdown, mathjax, hugo, tex, katex

I am new to Hugo, or any web development. I want to build a personal site to share my math notes, which are written in markdown. Precisely, I use the template [hugo-book](https://github.com/alex-shpak/hugo-book). But I find it does not support the math mode in markdown, i.e. it does not work if I write equations between `$$`. I do find some ways to write math equations, for example, I can use `{{< katex >}}`, but this is not convenient to change this for my markdown notes every time. So, is there a way that I can use `$$` to write math equations in this template?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an excellent guide here: https://bwaycer.github.io/hugo_tutorial.hugo/tutorials/mathjax/. Basically, you'd have to include some JavaScript code and then it'd work. However, it can cause some problems with the Markdown syntax. The blog describes some ways to prevent those.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate ...not really, when I use `<div>` and `</div>`, the text between `<div>` just disappear on the webpage. Do you know how to fix this? I did not change any code except the basic setup.

Comment: I haven't tried that myself, but, I think that page does have some more documentation about `<div>` too. If it's still not working, maybe, you can share a minimal reproduction or look into MathJax documentation.

Comment: The problem with the solution from https://bwaycer.github.io/hugo_tutorial.hugo/tutorials/mathjax/ is that it gives you Hugo version 2. Also, in the console, it writes: "WARNING: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips."

Answer (score 4):

For Mathjax 3, put this in the page source somewhere. I put it in `layouts/partials/head-additions.html`, but perhaps that is specific to the ananke theme:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

Now you can put this on your page and have it rendered:

```
Raw Mathjax block:
 

$$a_4 \ne b_4$$
```

like you'd expect.

Keep in mind though that according to the [commonmark
spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#backslash-escapes) (which Hugo follows
since it uses [goldmark](https://github.com/yuin/goldmark) internally), you
need to add two backslashes before punctuation characters such as `(` and `[`. So:

```
This shows as Mathjax \\(a \ne b\\), but this doesn't \(a \ne b\)

Likewise, this shows as Mathjax

\\[a \ne b\\]

but this doesn't:

\[a \ne b\]
```

Of course you can avoid that by using `$$ TeX Source $$`.

You can stop here.

But I went a step further, because I didn't like how Mathjax gives you a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) as described in [issue 131](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/131). I modified the approach suggested in that issue. Put this in the page source instead of the two simple `<script>` tags above:

```
{{- if or (.HasShortcode "mathjax/block") (.HasShortcode "mathjax/inline") -}}
<style>
.has-mathjax {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<script>
window.MathJax = {
  startup: {
    pageReady: () => {
      return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(() => {
        for (let element of document.getElementsByClassName("has-mathjax")) {
            element.style.visibility = "visible"
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
{{- end -}}
```

Put this in `layouts/shortcodes/mathjax/block.html`:

```
<div class="has-mathjax">
{{ .Inner }}
</div>
```

And this in `layouts/shortcodes/mathjax/inline.html`:

```
<span class="has-mathjax">{{ .Inner }}</span>
```

Now you can put this in your page source:

```
Mathjax block:
  
{{< mathjax/block >}}
\[a \ne 0\]
{{< /mathjax/block >}}

Inline shortcode {{< mathjax/inline >}}\(a \ne 0\){{< /mathjax/inline >}} with
Mathjax.
```

As you can see, using shortcodes also works around the issue of needing to add two backslashes before punctuation characters such as `(` and `[`.

(Full disclosure: This approach also appears on [an article on my blog](https://www.morch.com/posts/2021-07-24-mathjax-in-hugo/))

Answer (score 0):

The `toha` theme has the following `layout` file:

`toha/layouts/partials/math.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/katex/katex.min.css" | relURL }}">
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="{{ "/katex/katex.min.js" | relURL }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="{{ "/katex/auto-render.min.js" | relURL }}" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);">
    renderMathInElement(
        document.body,
        {
            delimiters: [
                {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true},
                {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false}
            ]
        }
    );
</script>
```

This allows you to use the same syntax as in @PeterVMorch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506928/1349673):

```
Inline mathjax \\(a \ne b\\) or display style $$a \ne b$$
```